# Can I get the property of a specific object in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-filter

I am using django-filters in my project. Let's say I get this address after a search:

?title=my title&ms=8

As you can see, I've searched for 'my title' and for a manuscript which the user sees as 'my manuscript', but whose `get` parameter (and ID) is 8.

Now, I'd like to add to my template a courtesy 'you've searched for' field. How can I show the title of that manuscript, rather than its ID?

I already have the ms objects in my view:

```
mstunes = MsTune.objects.all()
ms = Manuscript.objects.all() <- manuscripts
f = MsTuneFilter(request.GET, queryset=MsTune.objects.all())
return render(request, 'manuscript/mstune_list.html', {'mstunes': mstunes, 'f': f, 'request':request, 'ms': ms})
```

and I can indeed access them with `{{ms.all}}`. Is it possible to do something, in pseudo code, like:

```
show the ms.title of the ms object with id = request.GET.ms
```

?

My view:

```
def MsTuneList(request):

mstunes = MsTune.objects.all()
ms = Manuscript.objects.all() # can I get the ms.id from the request, with, say, request.ms, and then use it with get(id=ms)?
f = MsTuneFilter(request.GET, queryset=MsTune.objects.all())
return render(request, 'manuscript/mstune_list.html', {'mstunes': mstunes, 'f': f, 'request':request, 'ms': ms})
```

Comment: in `request.GET` is your url with the query parameters. you can get them from there and pass this value onto the template.

Comment: The value of request.GET.ms is 8 (see my question). I want a title.

Comment: use [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) method on ms queryset.

Comment: @hansTheFranz please read my question and see my parameters. django-filter produces a ms=id parameter. There's no 'title' in the parameters.

Comment: @HBMCS hansTheFranz has already gave you the right input. Get the ms param from the GET parameter like `get_ms = request.GET.get("ms")`. Then you can filter for the specific manuscript `searched_ms = Manuscript.objects.get(id=get_ms)`. Finally, you can pass this object to the template within your render method and display the the title in the template like `{{ serached_ms.title }}`.

Comment: AAaaaaah it's request.GET.get("ms") . I was trying with request.GET.ms, that's why I wasn't getting any results. I know I had the parameters in the URL but I didn't know how to access them from the view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should get the manuscript object which should have the title:-

```
Manuscript.objects.get(id=ms)
```

Note ms is the id (8 in your example) from the get parameter.

Comment: Of course it does. How can I get it on the template though?

Comment: pass it in the context.